# "AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

"AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'"

my selenium version is 4.4.3. I have used 4.3.0 version code but, there is no use .

My code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

username = ' ' # Change to your username here
password = ' ' # Change to your password here
url='https://academia.srmist.edu.in/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Email"]').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Password"]').send_keys(password)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="signinForm"]/div[6]/input').click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Selenium 4 has no more methods like `find_element_by_xpath`.
Use the following style instead:

```py
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Email"]').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Password"]').send_keys(password)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="signinForm"]/div[6]/input').click()
```

The same with all other methods like `find_element_by_css_selector`, `find_element_by_id` etc.